# organizing unittests in java/junit for testing classes with common api

Tags: java, junit, organization

I am implementing some elementary sorting algorithms (for the purpose of learning) ,and want to write unittests for them .All the sorting programs have the following common api

```
...
public static void sort(Comparable[] a);
...
public static boolean isSorted(Comparable[] a);
...
public static boolean isSorted(Comparable[] a),int from ,int to;
...
```

So,I wrote the following tests for testing the isSorted() method in SelectionSort

```
public class SelectionSortTests {
        String[] a ;    

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
            a = null;
    }

    @Test
    public void arraySortedSingleElement(){
        a = new String[]{"A"};
        Assert.assertTrue(SelectionSort.isSorted(a));
    }

    @Test
    public void arraySortedDistinctElements(){
        a = new String[]{"A","B","C","D"};
        Assert.assertTrue(SelectionSort.isSorted(a));
    }
    @Test
    public void arrayNotSorted(){
        a = new String[]{"A","B","C","B"};
        Assert.assertFalse(SelectionSort.isSorted(a));
    }
...
}
```

Now I feel that if I were to write tests for say InsertionSort,ShellSort etc ,they would look the same..Only the name of the class under test will change..

So,how should I organize the tests? Is a suite the answer or can I do better using reflection - may be write a driver program to which I can add a list of names of classes to be tested, and the driver invokes runs the common unit tests by passing the classname to it..

I realize this is a common situation..would like to know how this can be handled without spittle or cellotape

UPDATE:
thanks  @BevinQ and @Matthew Farwell ,I tried to solve this using Parameterized unit tests.
Used reflection to call the static method ..
Seems to work :) though I think it can still be refactored to avoid duplicate code

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class ParameterizedSortTests {
    private Class classToTest;
    private Method methodToTest;

    public ParameterizedSortTests(String packageName,String classToTest) {
        super();
        try {
            this.classToTest = Class.forName(packageName+"."+classToTest);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("failed to get class!!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    //method return collection of class names to be tested
    @Parameterized.Parameters
    public static  List<Object[]> classesToTest(){
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{ 
                {"elemsorts","SelectionSort"} ,
                {"elemsorts","InsertionSort"} 
        });
    }


    public void setMethod(String method,Class...args){
        try {
            this.methodToTest = this.classToTest.getMethod(method, args);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void arrayIsSorted(){
        setMethod("isSorted",Comparable[].class);
        String[] a = new String[]{"A","B","C","D"};
        Boolean arraySorted = null;
        try {
            arraySorted = (Boolean)this.methodToTest.invoke(null, new Object[]{a});
            System.out.println(this.methodToTest+"returned :"+arraySorted);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Assert.assertTrue(arraySorted);
    }

    @Test
    public void arrayIsNotSorted(){
        setMethod("isSorted",Comparable[].class);
        String[] a = new String[]{"A","B","C","B"};
        Boolean arraySorted = null;
        try {
            arraySorted = (Boolean)this.methodToTest.invoke(null, new Object[]{a});
            System.out.println(this.methodToTest+"returned :"+arraySorted);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //System.out.println("arraySorted="+arraySorted);
        Assert.assertFalse(arraySorted);
    }   

}
```

Comment: The difficulty is from making your methods static. If you were to make them not static and implement an interface. You will find life a lot easier. The way it is you will have to use reflection to call the methods if you want some structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @BevynQ says, you'll make life a lot easier for yourself if you make your methods non-static, and you implement an interface (called `Sorter` below). The you can easily use [Parameterized](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.java). This is a very quick example of how to use it, (untested, uncompiled)

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class SorterTest {
  @Parameters
  public static Iterable<Object[]> data() {
    return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
      { new SelectionSort() },
      { new BubbleSort() }
    });
  }

  private final Sorter sorter

  public SorterTest(Sorter sorter) {
    this.sorter = sorter;
  }

  @Test
  public void arraySortedSingleElement(){
    String[] a = new String[]{"A"};
    Assert.assertTrue(sorter.isSorted(a));
  }

  @Test
  public void arraySortedDistinctElements(){
    String[] a = new String[]{"A","B","C","D"};
    Assert.assertTrue(sorter.isSorted(a));
  }

  @Test
  public void arrayNotSorted(){
    String[] a = new String[]{"A","B","C","B"};
    Assert.assertFalse(sorter.isSorted(a));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for interface

```
public abstract class AbstractSortTests {
    String[] a ;    

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        a = null;
    }

   protected abstract Sorter getSorter();

    @Test
    public void arraySortedSingleElement(){
        a = new String[]{"A"};
        Assert.assertTrue(getSorter().isSorted(a));
    }

    @Test
    public void arraySortedDistinctElements(){
        a = new String[]{"A","B","C","D"};
        Assert.assertTrue(getSorter.isSorted(a));
    }
...
}

public class SelectionSortTests extends AbstractSortTests {

    protected Sorter getSorter(){
        return SelectionSort.getInstance();
    }

}

public class QuickSortTests extends AbstractSortTests {

    protected Sorter getSorter(){
        return QuickSort.getInstance();
    }

}
```

using reflection it is a bit messier but still do-able. I have not tested this code so might have
a couple of bugs, but have used this method in the past. Using interfaces would be the preferred method in 99% of cases.

```
public abstract class AbstractSortTests {
    String[] a ;    

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        a = null;
    }

   protected abstract Sorter getSorter();

    @Test
    public void arraySortedSingleElement() throws Exception{
        a = new String[]{"A"};
        Assert.assertTrue(executeMethod(getSorterClass(), "isSorted", a);
    }

    @Test
    public void arraySortedDistinctElements() throws Exception{
        a = new String[]{"A","B","C","D"};
        Assert.assertTrue(executeMethod(getSorterClass(), "isSorted", a);
    }

    private void executeMethod(Class<?> sortClass, String methodName, String[] values) throws Exception{
        return sortClass.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, new Class[]{String[].class}).invoke(null, new Object[]{values});
    }
...
}

public class SelectionSortTests extends AbstractSortTests {

    protected Class<?> getSorterClass(){
        return SelectionSort.class;
    }

}
```

Comment: The important point here being the introduction of the `Sorter` interface.

Answer (score 0):

why not something like this?

```
@Test
public void arraySortedDistinctElements(){
    a = new String[]{"A","B","C","D"};
    Assert.assertTrue(SelectionSort.isSorted(a));
    Assert.assertTrue(InsertionSort.isSorted(a));
    Assert.assertTrue(QuickSort.isSorted(a));
}
```

I don't think you have more than 10 different sortings to test. so it should be good.

otherway, you can declare all Sorting classes in Array and load using Class properties.

Comment: that would work..but then I would be editing all the test methods everytime I write a new Sort class.Ideally the name of the new class to be tested should be added in one place in the test program

Comment: then you can declare an array of classes and use class properties to load them. You have properties to define one time loading during initialization of JUnit test case [didn't remember the annotation name]